# Help with making sloping ground components

Tags: modeling, curve-modifier

So for a while now I’ve been working on creating environment assets for my sidescrolling platformer game, dividing up the environment assets into a assortment of individual pieces. These individual pieces are designed in a tile-like manner with each piece having dimensions being a multiple of 0.75 so that everything can be fitted together in a uniform manner.

[image]

The area however where I need help is with the slope parts. I made the slope parts with the curve modifier and initially everything seemed to be fine until I tried fitting in some 0.75 × 0.75 tile components with the slope parts.

[image]

[image]

As shown in the above screenshots, the problem is that the slope parts’ dimensions are not a multiple of 0.75 so they don’t fit with the other parts I’ve made.

I tried to make sure that the curve's dimensions were also a multiple of 0.75 as well as trying some other stuff as well to try and make slope fit properly.

[image]

But no matter what I just can't seem to get the slope to match the dimensions of the mesh & the curve.

[image]

How can I make sloping ground parts retain the same 0.75 scale as the other non-slopping parts I’ve made? I’ve haven’t had much luck trying to rectify this problem myself and I desperately need help, so any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you array the ground with a fixed count of 3 and one part is 1.5 m, then it will not fit the curve with 4.5 m width in X direction - because the curve is longer than 4.5 m (see it for example as a rope and then pull it straight). And when you switch to _Fit Curve_ instead of the count, three instances of 1.5 m will be to short to fit the curve, so the _Array_ modifier will add a fourth instance - resulting in an almost 6 m wide piece. Your parts need you be very thin to get close (close, but most likely not exact) to the desired size. Or you would have to sweep a profile along the curve.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm not liking the sound of making the parts thinner if I'm interpreting your suggestion correctly.  Also, what's sweeping a profile along a curve?  I don't know what that means.

Comment: Don't worry about sweeping profiles if you don't like making things thinner  A profile is a - basically infinitely thin - curve with the cross section of the part you want to create, and then you extrude it along the curve.